# Как решить проблему с кодировкой при записи в файл? UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, unicode

Есть скрипт:

```
import requests 
import json

def write_json(data):
    with open('posts.json','w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

def main():

    group_id='-30666517'
    r= requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get', params={'owner_id':group_id, 'count':100, 'offset':0})
    write_json(r.json())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Он должен делать запись в файл, но что-то идет не так и интерпретатор выдает ошибку

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0306' in position 38: character maps to <undefined>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Исправьте в строке `json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)`

 параметр `ensure_ascii=False` на `ensure_ascii=True`

Comment: @Alban это обход проблемы, а не настоящее её решение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open()` использует `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` по умолчанию (что-нибудь вроде `cp1252` на Windows), которая не поддерживает U+306 символ:

```
>>> '\u0306'.encode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0306' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Используйте кодировку, которая поддерживает необходимые символы, к примеру utf-8:

```
with open('posts.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

или экранируйте их в json формате (`ensure_ascii=True`), предполагая что `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` совместима с ascii.

Comment: спасибо большое)